JSON field doesn't map to object when projection and hibernate 6.2+
I have the java app with 21 java, hibernate-core 6.1.7 dependency, postgesql.
There is book table with adverts field, which is a json-field. I don't need this field in my entity, thus I get this info using projection like this:
public interface BookAdvertProjection {

    List<Advert> getAdverts();
}

public interface Advert {

    Long getSourceAdvertId();

    String getSource();

    Long getPrice();
}

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
    @Query(
        value = "SELECT adverts FROM book " +
                "WHERE id = :id",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    Optional<BookAdvertProjection> getBookAdvertProjection(@Param("id") int id);
}

And I use
public List<AdvertResource> getAdverts(String bookId) {
    return bookRepository.getBookAdvertProjection(bookId)
            .map(p -> p.getAdverts().stream())
            .orElse(Stream.empty())
            .map(converter::toAdvertResource)
            .toList();
}

Problem:
It works while hibernate-core version is 6.1.7. When I increased versions of my dependencies (include updating to hibernate 6.2+), I got the error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sourceAdvertId' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Could not find field for property during fallback access

So json-field doesn't map to Advert. How can I fix it? How can I get json-object using projection?
I couldn't find any info about this problem...
